# DataGridView column with buttons for only some entries?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` that needs a delete button for each row that has data: some rows may not have data. The `DataGridViewButtonColumn` seems to put a button in every cell, and I haven't been able to find a way to invisibilify (or perhaps even disable) certain buttons.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a bit of a hack...but you might be able to "remove" the button on certain rows...
see: [Datagridview, disable button/row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976889/winforms-datagridview-disable-button-row)

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewButtonCell = dgv.row(x).cell(y)
cell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
cell.value = String.Empty
cell.ReadOnly = True
```