# DataGridView On checked value,disable button

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGird is binding with `datasource` which have already some `checked` and `unchecked` values. I have to disable the button whose value is checked.

```
    private void disableManualBuyButtons()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvViewTickets.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbc = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
            cbc.TrueValue = true;
            if (cbc.Value.Equals(cbc.TrueValue))
            {
                DataGridViewButtonCell btn = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[8];
                btn.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I cant access btn.Enabled=false property.How does button disable?

Comment: Maybe you can replace the cell with a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and give a disabled `BackColor` which should be good enough !

Comment: Ahh, SO never disappoints Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976889/winforms-datagridview-disable-button-row

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx) article:

> The DataGridView control includes the DataGridViewButtonCell class for displaying cells with a user interface (UI) like a button. However, DataGridViewButtonCell does not provide a way to disable the appearance of the button displayed by the cell.

The work around suggested by article is to create your own column. You'll find full code in the article.

Comment: Is there another way to disable gridview button other than this article or to hide it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But this seams to be official Microsoft position on this matter and if there was an easy way to do this they wouldn't say that this is the best way. There is full code ready to be pasted just use it.