# Change a Cell into a Button in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a databound DataGridView. I want the cells of the two columns to contain a button instead of a regular cell.
Edit: Solved, now I need to figure out how to disable the button when a Cell contains NULL.

To enable adding of Columns to a specified position to a DataBound Datagridview, we have to set the Datagridviews AutoGenerateColumns Property to False before  adding  the Column.
Without doing so, all Columns that will be added will be placed on the right most end of the Datagridview and it will affect the first Column too.

But remember that the Colummn.Index Property will be affected.

```
dgv_dt is a DataTable  
dgv is the DataGridView  

dgv.AutoGenerateColumns=True

dgv.DataSource=dgv_dt
dgv.ClearSelection
dgv.Columns(0).HeaderText="FirstName"
dgv.Columns(1).HeaderText="Company ID"
dgv.Columns(2).HeaderText="Recent Picture"
dgv.Columns(2).Visible=False
dgv.Columns(3).HeaderText="Address"
dgv.Columns(4).HeaderText="Alive"

dgv.AutoGenerateColumns=False

Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
btn.HeaderText = "Click Data"
btn.Text = "Click Here"
btn.Name = "btn"
dgv.Columns.Insert(2,btn)
```

The code above will display the Datagridview and its Column.Index like this:

```
dgv.Columns(1) First Name
dgv.Columns(2) Company ID
dgv.Columns(3) Recent Picture 'This column is hidden, if this Contains NULL, ButtonCell is enabled/clickable
dgv.Columns(0) ButtonCell
dgv.Columns(4) Address
dgv.Columns(5) Alive
```

The Columns **Company ID** and **Recent Picture** contains a BLOB or NULL, if its a BLOB, the cell will be an Enabled Button and a Disabled Button if its NULL.

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Comment: Well yes, most of the samples I found here requires to Add additional column. But what I want is to change the existing column.

Comment: Delete existing and add new column on the same place in order

Comment: I have solved on the Adding a column with ButtonCells part, what I need now is how to disable the ButtonCell if a cell is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Set existing column to hidden `.Visible = false`.
Then add `DataGridViewButtonColumn` and check value of `CompanyID` column

if `BLOB` then button column enabled
if `NULL` then button column disabled

Comment: Im kind of lost in this, the DataGridViewButtonColumn does not have an Enable property that can either be set to True or False

Comment: Enable/disable `DataGridViewButtonColumn` can be too complicated. Here you can find some ideas for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976889/winforms-datagridview-disable-button-row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976889/winforms-datagridview-disable-button-row)

Comment: I have checked that post too and applied the 3rd answer by user295190, but there was an error pertaining to DataGridViewButtonCell cannot be of type DataGridViewTextBoxCell. Then again, I will try to wrap around MSDN as suggested by the other user from that post.